# Can I transfer from Heathrow T3 to T5 without a visa? I am a Philippine Passport holder

Tags: transit, lhr, visas-on-arrival, filipino-citizens

I will arrive Heathrow T3 at 6:10pm. I will depart from Heathrow T5 the next day at 6:30am for Madrid. I plan on staying at one of the airport hotels (probably the Sofitel at T5 since it is directly connected to the terminal), as there is nowhere to sleep in at the airport terminal.

Will I need to go through Immigration and Passport Control to transfer terminals and stay in the airport hotel?

Will I need a transit visa?

Comment: Not sure if there actually is an "airside" hotel in Heathrow. At least the Sofitel is "landside", so immigration would have to be cleared before it can be reached (which means that you would need a visa).

Comment: According to this answer here (https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100602013844AAnHBiI) - there are no "airside" hotels in Heathrow. So clearing immigration is unavoidable. However, the answer is 5 years old.

Comment: Insufficient info.  You have a Philippine passport but do not identify your destination plus what will you use for an exemption document.  Or do you have an exemption document?  Close voting as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @DCTLib There are no airside hotels in Heathrow. The Sofitel in T5 is landside but attached to the terminal by a walkway, ditto the Hilton in T4.

Comment: @DCTLib thank you very much for answering and for all the help!

Comment: @GayotFow That is all the information I need to put out there. Regardless if I put my final destination or not, the answer I will be expecting will be in general terms and only to answer the two questions I posted which are, (1) Will I need to go through Immigration and Passport Control to transfer terminals and stay in the airport hotel?, and (2) Will I need a transit visa? I have all the complete documents for my final destination (Schengen visa).

Comment: @FlipWanderlust, your edit helped to clarify.  But now your question is a duplicate that already has an answer.

Comment: @GayotFow thank you very much for the heads up. Sorry for the duplicate -- didn't get to see this existing one.

Comment: @FlipWanderlust, you should delete this one so your account will be free of forced closed questions

Comment: @GayotFow okay, thanks for the tip. but one last thing - transferring from T3 to T5 is airside right?

Comment: @GayotFow We generally don't want to delete duplicates: they're useful as search fodder. Visitors who find a question that's closed as a duplicate and unanswered are automatically redirected to the duplicate target.

Comment: @GayotFow if there is a need to delete my question, please do so. i cannot seem to find the delete button!?

Comment: @FlipWanderlust, read http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/why-am-i-in-danger-of-being-blocked